# Using eslint causes my string to fail with no-irregular-whitespace error

Tags: node.js, express, eslint

I've started to use eslint (migrated from tslint) but this is throwing an error, not sure why!

**Code snippet**

```
const url = `${this.url}​/members​/${memberId}​/profile`;
```

It's super strange as other similar lines of code are not causing a problem!  I'm not sure how to resolve this problem.

**Full error message**

```
Irregular whitespace not allowed.
```

eslint version = `^7.31.0`

Thanks!!

**Update**

I have the following config but it produces an error when running lint

```
plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "react"],
extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
],
rules: {},
```

**Error message**

```
ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-react".
```

**Solution**

Add this to the eslint config file:

```
rules: {
    "no-irregular-whitespace": [
        "error",
        { skipRegExps: true, skipTemplates: true },
    ],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your eslint config has:

```
"extends": [
  "plugin:react/recommended"
]

...

"plugins": [
  "react"
]
```

Comment: I have the following (see updated) and it's causing an error.  The config is what I had before plus your suggestion

Comment: npm i --save-dev eslint-plugin-react

Comment: thanks for this, I've ran that and then rerun $ yarn lint but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: actually, i was being dumb and switching between several things at once.  The code base is node (and not react)

Comment: managed to get this fixed, by adding a rules in the eslint config file